# react native iOS solution get error in third party files

Tags: reactjs, react-native

config.h & more xcode build get error,  i just flow the step in 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: Try: `cd ./node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4 && ./configure && make && make install` - Please make sure you select your version of glog, I am using 0.3.4.

Comment: Thanks ji, its worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the “config.h” not found error or related this in xocde, just do the below steps,

```
1.  Close Xcode.
2.  cd <Project-Folder>/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4
3.  Run ./configure
4.  Run make
5.  Run make install
6.  Open Xcode and try building the Project.
```